# Cloning Power BI DirectQuery into a regular query

Tags: import, powerbi, powerquery

I have a Power Bi dataset that someone shared with me. I would like to import it into Power Bi Desktop and transform its data

I used DirectQuery to import the dataset and I managed to create a calculated table:
My_V_Products = CALCULATETABLE(V_Products)

However, when I try using TransformData, I do not see this table. I guess this is due to the fact that this is not actually a table created from a query but from a DAX.

Is there a way to import the entire table using a query or convert the data to transformable data?

Answer (score 0):

Only if the Dataset is on a premium capacity.  If it is you can connect to the XMLA endpoint for the workspace using the Analysis Services connector, and create an Import table using a custom DAX query, like `evaluate V_Products`.